# HSSFWorkbook Error

Tags: java, excel, jframe, poi-hssf

Hi I am having an error when I try to use the HSSF Workbook. See this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
    at digicare.tracking.serial.BulkUpload.UploadProgress$1read2.run(UploadProgress.java:95)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my code:

```
try {
    file = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath));
    try {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    } catch (Exception e2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error1" + e2.getMessage());
    }

    //HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //HSSFRow row;
    //HSSFCell cell;  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error1" + e1.getMessage()); 
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error2 "+ e.getMessage()); 
}
```

It seems like whenever I try to use the workbook part it returns an error

Comment: You should probably de-abbreviate HSSF for a clearer question. :)

Comment: I also don't know what HSSF mean hahaha :D

Comment: Looks like you have the POI jars at build time, but not at run time. Have you tried ensuring they're all available when your code runs?

Comment: I have put it inside my project and export the project in jar. so jar files should be there

Comment: As in your have put dependency jars inside your main jar? That doesn't work by default, unless you take care with classloaders / wrappers

Comment: yes. so how would I call the dependency jars? should I call it separately on my jnlp file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the POI jars in your build path.It says No class found.HSSF is associated with XLS files.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605181/how-can-i-add-the-apache-poi-library-in-and-eclipse-project) for an example in Eclipse.

Depending on which IDE you use, the setup process might vary.

Comment: yeah I have all the POI jar files. last time I used the POI it worked fine, that is web application. but this one is a java web start application and now its not working.

Comment: If it was working previously,you might want to track down what was the recent change you made.Are you using any build tool for your application?

Comment: it worked before in a web application. I am now using it on a web-start application. is the implementation of poi the same in web-start applications?

Comment: Yes,its the same.It does not have to do with what application you use in the front end,it is just a third party library.What exactly is your use case here,the excel is getting uploaded from the front end?

Comment: yes excel is being uploaded from front end. Now my eclipse is also not working. it hangs on start up